# Should there be a "blogged" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

For questions featured on [QotW](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw), or otherwise [blogged](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/) about, is it worth having a [blogged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogged) tag? It would be an easy way of seeing from a person's profile if they had questions which had been blogged about, and how many. It would also be a way of raising awareness about the blog (which I appreciate is still in incubation).

Comment: Leaving a comment will probably suffice @fredley :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say no.  [blogged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogged) would be a meta tag, rather than a tag about the question's content.  Users who care about the blog can just go and look at it :P

Answer (score 0):

There are already enough meta tags on the site itself, no more please.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of tags are you thinking about?